# Find Input box next to the word

Tags: jquery

I have a form...

```
<form id='form1'>
   First Name:
   <input type="text"> 
</form>
```

I want to be able to find the word `First Name` and then look for the following input and add the value "Joe". There could be label tags around the name or div/span tags around the input as well. Above is just a basic example.

My code looks something like this but does not function properly of course. Thanks.

```
$('#form1').text($(this).find('First Name').next().val('Joe'));
```

Comment: Instead, can't you assign an id for input and select it with #textboxid ?

Comment: You need to be FAR more specific. "There could be label tags around the name or div/span tags around the input as well." isn't specific enough, that could result in 20-30 different ways that the input could be wrapped resulting in that many * 5 different ways to do it in jQuery.

Comment: @KevinB This is best I could explain since the form can be different every page load. The text and input will often be the same though

Comment: Is it also possible for `First Name:` to be missing a `:`, or to be wrapped in any number of different possible elements? that makes it near impossible to create one script that will work in all situations unless the input has a common name or id or it is the only input in the form every time.

Comment: @j08691 this did not work for me. sorry

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea, searching for a label in this way will force the browser to search a lot more elements than it should. You should use an id for the text box, and get the element via id.

```
<label for="firstname">First Name: </label><input id="firstname"/>

$('#firstname').val('joe');
```

Alternately:

```
<label for="firstname">First Name: </label><input id="firstname" class="firstname"/>

$('input.firstname').val('joe');
```

or

```
<label for="firstname">First Name: </label>
<input id="firstname" inputtype="firstname"/>

$('input[inputtype="firstname"]').val('joe');
```

Comment: The label id's are ever changing... I can't rely on something that is not static

Comment: perhaps a class or name then? ideally you would want to use the id (if you could harness it) because it is orders of magnitude faster than any other option.

Comment: Those too change. The text stays the same and the input type to the right is the same. That is why I can't think of any other way to do a search than this way

Comment: you could always add a class (to those which already appear). alternately if that is not an option (can't imagine why), you can add a custom attribute. inputtype="firstname"

Comment: This last option will perform the worst. There are optimized functions in browsers to select by class and id.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to associate labels and inputs in HTML would be to use the `<label>` tag:

```
<form id='form1'>
    <label for='firstName'>First Name</label>
    <input type='text' name='firstName' id='firstName'/>
</form>
```

Label's `for` is associated to the input by ID, so to select the input from the label you could do:

```
document.getElementById($('label[innerHTML="First Name"]').get(0).htmlFor).value += Joe;
```

Or just use the input's id:

```
document.getElementById('firstName').value += 'Joe';
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery isn't meant for selecting text, it is meant for selecting elements. If you named your input `first_name` for example, you could select the input directly with

```
$("input[name=first_name]", "#form1")
```

There is absolutely no reason to select an input based on the text that comes before it when the input MUST have a name id or class to be used by the html page in any useful way.

Comment: I need to find the position of the matched word first to determine it's location. Once I find that, I can then locate the position of the input to the right unless you have something better

Comment: "to the right" isn't going to work though. to the right could mean traversing up 2 elements over one and down 4, or up 1 over 2 and down 1, or up 0 over 1 and down 6, etc. What about forms that are using tables for layout where the labels and inputs are in two completely different rows?

Comment: If you tell us what all of the possibilities are, we may be able to give you a specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/uhicic/2/edit)*

Simle: use `.eq()` ( or `:eq()` )
I suppose that inside a form your desired input will be (e.g.) the first one, right:

```
<form id='form1'>  
   First Name:
   <input type="text">  
   Last  Name:
   <input type="text">  
   Comment:
   <input type="text">     
</form>
```

This is all you need:

```
$('#form1 input').eq(0).val('Joe');
```

So one day you can calmly use more languages in your page :)